# Is it possible to generate deep infrasound with subwoofer and a pipe?

Tags: waves, acoustics, vibrations

I would like to check if infrasound noise can make people feel weird (as in a "haunted" house). Some people claim that noises of such frequency may be the cause of "paranormal" sensation in humans.

> The evidence linking infrasound to reputed hauntings is tentative but intriguing. Apparitions in peripheral vision, cold shivers and feelings of discomfort and fear have all been reported in places where infrasound is present. Some notable research in this area was conducted by Vic Tandy, an engineer from Coventry University. Working in the laboratory, Tandy and his colleagues had strange experiences which led to suggestions the place was haunted. When he investigated the lab building, Tandy found a ventilation fan was producing an infrasonic standing wave with a frequency of 19Hz. As soon as he switched off the fan, the standing wave disappeared and the unusual sensations evaporated. This discovery – a possible connection between infrasound and his experiences – prompted Tandy to look for infrasound in other allegedly haunted sites. A second investigation took place at a 14th century cellar in Coventry, where people had seen apparitions. At this site he also found a spike of infrasound at 19Hz.

quote from:http://www.sarahangliss.com/extras/Infrasonic/background.htm#

I have found [this](http://arpast.org/newsevents/articles/article59.pdf) article, however this journal doesn't seem reliable.

On previous cited website I found that they built an infrasound generator using a [loudspeaker in a sewer pipe](http://www.sarahangliss.com/extras/Infrasonic/photogallery.htm), however they didn't write about details of said generator.

So how can I make such generator? Neither I nor anyone on my university have a background in acoustics.

What should I consider in such construction? I would like to reproduce said Angliss' experiment using my university's lecture hall.

To sum up:

1. is it possible to generate infrasound using such equipment?
2. If yes, how to do this?

Comment: Yes. You connect your speaker to a really long pipe. How deep do you want to go? 1Hz? That's something like 85m (280 feet) of sewer pipe. :-) (PS: I built a sewer pipe subwoofer as a kid, once. They work remarkably well, even though they don't have quite the "punch" that one would want. The bandwidth is just too small. Today I would probably know better how to design it right.)

Comment: About 10 Hz is enough. I have at most 20 meters of available space. How to calculate optimal length? And which loudspeaker should I choose?

Comment: Build a quarter wave pipe, for starters. That brings you to something like 8m. You can fold it around one corner of the room, that way it will make you feel sick from both corners. Be careful with the windows. Seriously. If you do this right with a couple hundred W speaker and amplifier it might blow them out. :-)

Comment: I wonder if the claimed effect would work generating appearant infrasound by the way of missing fundamental effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_fundamental . I guess not, since I think the unpleasant sensation is done by effect of infrasound on the body (e.g. lung), not hears.

Comment: NB: the "making-ill corridor" effect due to infrasound occured in the research lab of my engineer school "Telecom Paris", that occured to be at the top of signal processing and psychoacoustic. They measured huge dB in infrasounds there, and discovered that the anti-fire doors with small spacing at mid-corridor were creating a geant Helmholtz resonator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_resonance , as in a oboe :-) . Maybe that's a way to generate what you want (might be difficult to control, though).

Comment: @CuriousOne How did you connect the speaker to the pipe? Do you mind writing an answer?